# How to send parameter file_path to controller (laravel 5)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

My Code is like this :

```
function showAjaxPdf(file_path)
        {
            var file_path = "test/test_one.pdf".replace(/\\/g,"/");
            alert(file_path);
            $.ajax({
                url: "news/test/" + file_path,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

My function test in controller is like this :

```
public function getTest($file_path)
    {
        die($file_path);      
    }
```

The results of the response : `test`

Should the results of the response : `test/test_one.pdf`

How do I get the results of the response : `test/test_one.pdf`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your routing is working correctly, add the file_path to the ajax data:

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: "news/test",
data: {file_path: file_path},
success: function(response)
{
alert(response);
}
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**PHP:**

```
$file_path = $request->file_path;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests